# Linear combination of symmetric matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Today my friend told that any matrix can be written as a linear combination of symmetric matrices and skew symmetric matrices.. we had this question that a linear transformation $T:M_n(R) \to M_n(R)$ which maps every symmetric matrix or skew symmetric matrices to zero matrix, find the rank of the linear transformation. He said simply 0, but i have a doubt.. is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, then$$A=\frac{A+A^t}{2}+\frac{A-A^t}{2},$$and$$(A+A^t)^t=A^t+(A^t)^t=A^t+A=A+A^t,$$so $A+A^t$ is symmetric, while$$(A-A^t)^t=A^t-(A^t)^t=A^t-A=-(A-A^t),$$so $(A-A^t)$ is skew symmetric. So it is true that every matrix can be written as a linear combination of symmetric and skew symmetric matrices. Thus a linear transformation mapping symmetric and skew symmetric matrices to $0$ is actually zero, thus it does have rank $0$.