# Supplementary subspaces of space of square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M_n(K)$ be the vector space of square matrices of size n, and
$$M_n^s(k) = \{A \in M_n(K) | A^t = A\}$$
and
$$M_n^a(k) = \{A \in M_n(K) | A^t = -A\}$$
subspaces.

I need to show that these subspaces are supplementary in $M_n(K)$.

I guess I should show that $M_n^s(k) + M_n^a(k) = M_n(K)$ and that $M_n^s(k) \cap M_n^a(k) = \{0\}$, but I don't know how to do this. Or is there another way?

Comment: The first equation just says that any matrix can be written as the sum of a symmetric matrix and an antisymmetric matrix. Do you know how to do this? (If not, do you know how to write a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ as the sum of an even function and an odd function?)

Comment: As for the second equation, just use the definitions of the two subspaces: What does it mean for a matrix to be in both?

Comment: For the first part, you might be interested by this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532010/linear-combination-of-symmetric-matrices

Comment: Thanks a lot! It wasn't hard but I didn't know where to start. You were both very useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

show that: $\forall A \in M_n(K)$ there is a [decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Properties) as sum of a symmetric ant an anti-symmetric part as
$$
A=A_s+A_a 
$$

with 
$$A_s=\frac {A+A^T}{2} \qquad A_a=\frac {A-A^T}{2}
$$