# Find bilinear forms such that ...

Tags: bilinear-form

Let $\langle \ ,\ \rangle : \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ given by:
$$ ⟨(u_1, u_2),(v_1, v_2)⟩ = u_1(v_1 + v_2) + u_2v_2 $$

$1$. Is it bilinear? And symmetric?

$ ⟨(a (u_1, u_2) + b (v_1 + v_2) , (w_1, w_2)⟩ = a ⟨u,w⟩ + b ⟨v,w⟩ $, $ \ \forall u,v, w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $ \forall a,b\in \mathbb{R} $

$  ⟨(u_1, u_2) , (a (v_1, v_2) + b (w_1 + w_2) ⟩ = a ⟨u,v⟩ + b ⟨u,w⟩ $, $ \ \forall u,v, w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $ \forall a,b\in \mathbb{R} $

So $\langle \ ,\ \rangle$ is bilinear, but

$ ⟨u,v⟩ \neq ⟨v,u⟩ $, $\  \forall u,v \in \mathbb{R}^2$

So $\langle \ ,\ \rangle$ is not symmetric.

**$2$. Find bilineal forms $⟨ \ ,\ ⟩_+,⟨\ ,\ ⟩_−$ such that:**

**(a)** $⟨ \ ,\ ⟩ = ⟨\ ,\ ⟩_+ + ⟨\ ,\ ⟩_−$

**(b)** $⟨u, v⟩_+ = ⟨v, u⟩_+$

**(c)** $⟨u, v⟩_− = −⟨v, u⟩_−$

$ \forall u,v \in \mathbb{R}^2$

Find the matrix for $⟨ \ ,\ ⟩$, $⟨ \ ,\ ⟩_+$ and $⟨\ ,\ ⟩_−$ in canonical basis.

Is it even possible to find $⟨\ ,\ ⟩_+$ and $⟨\ ,\ ⟩_−$ that fits in (a), (b) and (c) at the same time? Any help to find that bilinear forms? Thanks!

Comment: As I read question 2, $<\ ,\ >$ is the form from question 1, and you are supposed to find the forms $<\ ,\ >_+$ and $<\ ,\ >_-$

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know exactly what that forms mean... I have not used that notation before

Comment: They're just two bilinear forms.  Call them $f$ and $g$ if you like.  [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130352/prove-that-every-bilinear-map-can-be-written-as-a-sum-of-bilinear-symmetric-map) will help

Comment: Okok now I understand. Anyway, is it even possible to find $⟨\ ,\ ⟩_+$ and $ ⟨\ ,\ ⟩_−$ that fits in (a), (b) and (c) at the same time?

Comment: Yes.  The question is write a given bilinear form ($<\ ,\ >$) as the sum of a symmetric bilinear from ($<\ ,\ >_+$) and an asymmetric bilinear form ($<\ ,\ >_-$).  The answer linked in my previous comment should show you how to do that.

Comment: You right! That's an interesting theorem! Then $⟨u ,v ⟩_+ = u_1v_1 + \frac{1}{2} (u_1v_2+u_2v_1) + u_2v_2$ and $⟨u ,v ⟩_− = \frac{u_1v_2-u_2v_1}{2} $ !! Thanks a lot!